# Get list of child records

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a database that looks like this:

```
tbl_Seminar
   ID
   isActive


tbl_SeminarFees
   ID
   seminar_id -- foreign key
   fee_text
```

I want to get all seminars that are active (isActive ==1) and a list of the fees associated with that seminar.  Each Seminar may have n records in tbl_SeminarFees that are its fees.  I am able to return a linq structure that returns me a list of objects that look like this `{seminar, SeminarFee}` but I wanted to create a nested structure that looks like this:

```
{seminar, List<SeminarFee>}
```

What should my linq query look like?

here is my linq currently:

```
var results = from s in context.Seminar
              join p in context.SeminarFees on
              s.ID equals p.SeminarID

              where s.IsActive == 1
              select new 
              {
                  Seminar = s,
                  Fees = p

              };
```

How do I change this to get a list of these: `{seminar, List<SeminarFee>}`

Thanks

**UPDATE**

@lazyberezovsky gave me a good idea to use a group join and into another variable.  But then how do I loop through the result set.  Here is what I have now:

```
foreach (var seminarAndItsFeesObject in results)
            {
                //do something with the seminar object 
                //do something with the list of fees
            }
```

This however gives me the following error:

```
    Argument type 'SeminarFees' does not match the 
corresponding member type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SeminarFees]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? Entity Framework? LINQ to SQL? NHibernate? Something else?

Comment: LinqToSql is what I am using

Answer (score 6):

You can use [group join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301847.aspx) which groups inner sequence items based on keys equality (a.k.a. *join..into*) to get all fees related to seminar:

```
var results = from s in context.Seminar
              join f in context.SeminarFees on
                   s.ID equals f.SeminarID into fees // here 
              where s.IsActive == 1
              select new 
              {
                  Seminar = s,
                  Fees = fees
              };
```

You can't call `ToList()` on server side. But you can map results on client later.

---

**BTW** You can define [navigation property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx) `Fees` on `Seminar` object:

```
public virtual ICollection<SeminarFee> Fees { get; set; }
```

In this case you will be able load seminars with fees:

```
var results = context.Seminar.Include(s => s.Fees) // eager loading
                     .Where(s => s.IsActive == 1);
```

Comment: +1 however, you could  underline that the only difference from a normal to a group join is the `into`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks :) You are right, I'll point the difference

Comment: This makes sense but I am getting a runtime error when I try to access the individual items in results.  The error is: Argument type 'SeminarFees' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SeminarFees]'

Comment: How do I map the results to the client?

Comment: @majid looks like you are trying to assign single fee object to collection of fees

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I updated the question.  Please look at the section after the update.  Thank you.

Comment: @majid you didn't provide actual code how you use query results. Btw I think your problem worth another question

Answer (score 1):

```
  var results = from s in context.Seminar
                join p in context.SeminarFees on s.ID equals p.SeminarID
                where s.IsActive == 1
                group p by s into grouped
                select new {
                  Seminar = grouped.Key,
                  Fees = grouped.ToList()
                };
```

Comment: How do I get access to each of the objects in the list?  I am getting this error: Argument type 'SeminarFees' does not match the corresponding member type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[SeminarFees]'

Comment: I get that error when trying to access the elements in a foreach loop